# Is it safe to add another field to custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it safe to add a new meta box (custom field) in a Wordpress custom post type? I want to make sure it will not reset all my already established posts of this post type if I add to it in the backend. Its all in the backend as functions in the functions.php. I highly doubt it will but with so many posts, I want to make 100% sure since I heard somewhere it was not safe (which doesn't make sense to me but again, 100% certainty is required here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should always make backups of your website (especially the database), use versioning with git and/or set up an development environment if you change critical things in your projects.

It is safe to add new custom fields to any post type as long as you do not override an existing custom field by a naming conflict so choose a unique name for your new custom fields which do not conflict with a Plugin or other custom fields.

Any further information you can find within the Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields